# java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[0].name()"

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-test

i am doing an integration test or e2e. I have method to find All Person ( Entity ) and updatePersonTestShouldReturnTrue. When i start test i got an error in shouldReturnListOfUsers method in test class and the same error in updatePersonTestShouldReturnTrue method. I cant understand what did wrong.
Code:

```
 MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /person/
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.controller.PersonController
           Method = com.controller.PersonController#findAll()

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = [{"id":null,"name":"Test","surname":"Test1","date_of_birth":"10 Year"}]
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.name()"

    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:304)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.lambda$value$2(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
    at com.PersonControllerTest.shouldReturnListOfUsers(PersonControllerTest.java:74)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Function with name: name does not exist.
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.function.PathFunctionFactory.newFunction(PathFunctionFactory.java:71)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.FunctionPathToken.evaluate(FunctionPathToken.java:38)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:62)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:99)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:107)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:179)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:386)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:370)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:301)
    ... 71 more

}
```

Entity class:

```
package com.entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Person(String name, String surname, String date_of_birth) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Size(min = 2,max = 48,message = "Size must be between 1 and 48 symbol")
    @NotBlank(message = "Please input data")
    private String name;


    @Column(name = "surname")
    @Size(min = 2,max = 48,message = "Size must be between 2 and 48 symbol")
    @NotBlank(message = "Please input data")
    private String surname;

//    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
//    @Pattern( regexp = "^((?:(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9])\\d{2})(-)(?:(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])(-)31)|((0[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(-)(29|30))))$|^(?:(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(-)02(-)29)$|^(?:(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9])\\d{2})(-)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(-)(?:0[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])$")
    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    @Size(min = 1,max = 10,message = "Size must be between 1 and 10 symbol")
    @NotBlank(message = "Please input years old of person")
    private String date_of_birth;



}
```

---

Controller

```
package com.controller;


import com.entity.Person;
import com.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/person")
@Validated
@Controller
public  class PersonController {


    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Person> findAll(){

        List<Person> list= personService.findAllPerson();
        if (list.isEmpty()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No such person founded in list of persons ");
        }

        return list;

    }



    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Optional<Person> findById(@PathVariable("id")Long id){

        Optional<Person> list= personService.findById(id);
        if (list.isEmpty()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No such person founded in list of persons ");
        }

        return list;


    }






    @PutMapping(path = "/")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<Person> updatePerson(@Valid @RequestBody Person person){

        personService.updatePerson(person);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build() ;

    }

}
```

Repository

```
package com.repository;

import com.entity.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,Long> {



}
```

Service

```
package com.service;

import com.entity.Person;
import com.repository.PersonRepository;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Component
@Service
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonService {

    private PersonRepository personRepository;



    @Autowired
    public void setPersonRepository(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public List<Person> findAllPerson(){

        return  personRepository.findAll();


    }

    public Optional<Person> findById(Long id){

        return  personRepository.findById(id);
    }


    public Person addNewPerson(Person person){

        return personRepository.save(person);

    }

    public Person updatePerson(Person person){

         return personRepository.save(person);

    }












}
```

Test class:

```
package com;

import com.controller.PersonController;
import com.entity.Person;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.service.PersonService;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;


@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(PersonController.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:testApplication.properties")
public class PersonControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private PersonService personService;






    @Test
    void shouldReturnListOfUsers() throws Exception {

        when(personService.findAllPerson())
                .thenReturn(List.of(new Person("Test","Test1","10 Year")));

        this.mockMvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/person/"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.size()", Matchers.is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name()").value("Test"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[2].surname()").value("Test1"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[3].date_of_birth()").value("10 Year"));

    }



    @Test
    public void updatePersonTestShouldReturnTrue() throws Exception {

        Person RECORD_1 = new Person();
        RECORD_1.setId(1L);
        RECORD_1.setName("Test1");
        RECORD_1.setSurname("Test1_2");
        RECORD_1.setDate_of_birth("22 Years");

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(5L);
        person.setName("Test2");
        person.setSurname("Test2_2");
        person.setDate_of_birth("55 Years");



        Mockito.when(personService.findById(RECORD_1.getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(RECORD_1));
        Mockito.when(personService.updatePerson(person)).thenReturn(person);

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockRequest = MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/person/")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(this.mapper.writeValueAsString(person));

        mockMvc.perform(mockRequest)
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Test1_2"));

    }










}
```

testApplication.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-plateform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Test task</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```